# Alert de javascript no funciona en webview android

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview-android

pensé que era una sola linea pero no se me activa:

Aquí les dejo el código:

```
WebView myWeb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb);
        myWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWeb.loadUrl("http://mi.pagina.com");
    }
```

Como podrán ver, la linea que yo pensé que se ponía únicamente es:

```
myWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Aclaración: 
Los efectos de materialize me andan perfecto, lo que NO me funciona es los avisos de la ventana de javascript, por ejemplo, cuando quiero eliminar un usuario, en la pagina web sale un mensaje preguntando si estoy seguro de eliminar o no, y si le pongo aceptar me lo elimina, pues eso es lo que no sale en mi WEBVIEW.

Alguna idea?

Ahora estoy probando con este código que en teoría debería andar pero se me cierra la aplicación "se ha detenido":

```
  WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://mi.pagina.com");
    }
```

Comment: ¿entonces solo los alert  no aparecen?

Comment: Exactamente, solo los alert, lo otro anda perfecto.

Comment: @Strelok veo tienes webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); en verdad no se muestra el alert? podrías agregar el código html de tu página, si tienes habilitado WebChromeClient no deberías tener problema, a menos que el problema sea la página.

Comment: Parece que el problema es mi móvil, ya que lo probé en el emulador bluestack y en el móvil de un amigo y funciona perfecto. Por que sera que en el mio no funciona?

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que usar [WebChromeClient](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=752) para esto.

Un ejemplo:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     myWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb);
     myWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
     myWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
     myWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

     myWeb.loadUrl("http://mi.pagina.com");
 }
```

Puedes intentar poner este código para ver los errores generados:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tu conexión a Internet podría no estar activa o " + error , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Por que myWeb y luego mWebView? te referis a lo mismo?

Comment: Probé tu código, reemplazando mWebView por myWeb y se me cierra la app, no funciona :(

Comment: @Strelok si, fue un error. Ya lo corregí. ¿Cuál es el error que aparece ahora?

Comment: probé tu código y me compila perfecto, luego instale la app pero al abrirla se cierra. Intenté quitarle la linea: myWeb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);  pero tampoco funciona

Comment: no sé si tambien incluiste la linea setWebViewClient(), la acabo de agregar. Para saber por qué sucede el error deberías probar en el emulador. [Aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2835694/4987172) hay una respuesta donde se ve la correcta declaración. Tal vez sea un error relacionado con otra cosas pero no sabremos hasta probar en el emulador

Comment: Lo pruebo en mi móvil. Dice "Se ha detenido la aplicación myApp". Acabo de ver tu pagina dice que no se debería necesitar mas que eso. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: acabo de poner el código tal cual lo tengo en la pregunta principal.

Comment: actualice mi respuesta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56608/discussion-between-strelok-and-rene-limon).

Comment: necesitaría tu ayuda nuevamente. Necesito poder ajuntar archivos desde mi web view. Podrías ayudarme?

Comment: @Strelok formula una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Un alert de JavaScript

```js
    alert("Stackoverflow.com is cool!");
```

que se encuentra de una página web que cargamos dentro de un WebView no puede mostrar el mensaje por default, tendrías como opción habilitar `WebChromeClient()` y obviamente habilitar la ejecución de Javascript:

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es necesaria esta linea?  myWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 O con esas 3 que me dijiste alcanza?

Comment: @Strelok El WebViewClient no es necesario, las 3 que comento son suficientes y necesarias.

Comment: muchas gracias! Ahora tengo un pequeño problema, el "file" no me abre, acabo de hacer una post al respecto, podrías ayudarme por favor?

Comment: @Strelok a que te refieres con el "file" ?

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60835/no-se-abre-el-file-de-materialize-en-webview ahí lo explico

Comment: @Strelok Up es que usas en Framework Materialize! dime algo, en verdad funciona en otro dispositivo? recuerda que el WebView en Android esta limitado!

Comment: No entendí, pues todo funciona perfecto menos eso que te comente de subir img

Comment: @Joresys aun no logro solucionar esto del todo, como puedo comunicarme contigo?