# como ver los alert de mi pagina en un webview android

Tags: android, webview-android

Buenos dias, estoy mostrando mi web en un `webview` en android todo funciona bien menos los alert de la pagina que cargo en el `webview`, por ejemplo :

```
alert("registro ingresado!");
```

pero el webview no lo muestra. gracias.

Comment: Te paso un [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271898/javascript-alert-not-working-in-android-webview) en el site en ingles donde resuelven tu problema. Fíjate también como el OP realiza la pregunta, aportando código y estableciendo el escenario de la prueba que está realizando.

Comment: Anteriormente fue preguntado esto pero no fue aceptado, por lo tanto no puede cerrarse: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60771/alert-de-javascript-no-funciona-en-webview-android he agregado la respuesta aquí

Answer (score 1):

Un alert de JavaScript

```js
    alert("Stackoverflow.com is cool!");
```

que se encuentra de una página web que cargamos dentro de un WebView no puede mostrar el mensaje por default, tendrías como opción habilitar `WebChromeClient()` y obviamente habilitar la ejecución de Javascript:

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Disculpa por haber replicado una respuesta , pero si la gente que pregunta no busca ni siquiera su misma pregunta en el foro ,

Comment: Hola bruno, Es mejor referenciar a un contenido si este fue marcado como respuesta correcta o guiar a los usuarios para evitar agregar varias preguntas/respuestas similares. El [plagio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagio) está mal visto en nuestra comunidad